# Using Mendeley with InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, mendeley

Currently I am writing up my thesis. I am using Word for writing and InDesign for figures and graphics. The only reason why I use Word at all is because I can insert Mendeley citations there.

Is there any way I can use Mendeley citations directly in InDesign? This would make things much easier as I wouldn't need to use Word at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy and paste citations in text or HTML format by selecting a citation in Mendeley Desktop and selecting Edit -> Copy Citation.

You can then paste the result into any program that supports text or rich text in HTML format.

The Mendeley Desktop cite-o-matic plugin only supports Microsoft Word and LibreOffice out of the box.  If a third party developer is interested in integrating it with their software this is possible, https://github.com/mendeley/openoffice-plugin provides Python code as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to find a way to add citations and have a reference list at the end of the document. Use Zotero as a citation manager then use [this script](https://github.com/ka1/zot2indd) to import your Zotero Citations to InDesign and use Latex-like syntax (i.e. `\cite{author1998}` ) to create a linked reference list.

It works really well and it makes the whole referencing process completely pain free. There are plenty of instructions on the script page